# VueJS Watcher is not triggered while watching deep object changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I got a codesandbox that reproduces my problem: [codesandbox example watcher not triggering](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-snyder-57ics?file=/src/components/UselessRoute1.vue:734-796).

I am working on a component that relies on an object with data that can be dynamically added to the object, so for example, in a seperate `.js` file, I am exporting the following object:

```
export default {
  defaultSection1: {
    displayName: 'Action',
  },
  defaultSection2: {
    displayName: 'Thriller',
  },
}
```

I import this object in my component.

I got a debouncer setup from Lodash so that when data changes, it only fires the watcher once after two seconds. The watcher **IS triggered** perfectly fine for the data that is already in the object (type in the input text box in my example, and the watcher is triggered). But when I dynamically add data to the object, the watcher is **not triggered** at all. Only when I change routes back and forth, the data is updated, but the watcher is not triggered. Why is this? What can I do so that the watcher is triggered when data is dynamically being added to an object.

```
methods: {
    fetchAndUpdateData(){
      console.log('Fetching data...')
    },
    addCustomSection(){
      //The watcher should be triggered when this function is called
      const newSectionId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000); 
      this.data[newSectionId] = {
         displayName: 'Custom'
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    dataWatcher() {
      return this.data;
    },
    updateData() {
      return debounce(this.fetchAndUpdateData, 2000);
    },
  },
  watch: {
    dataWatcher: {
      handler() {
        console.log('Watcher triggered')
        this.updateData();
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
```

Why is the watcher not triggered, when clearly the data is being changed?

Another thing I noticed that is quite strange, is that in `Vue 3.0`, the watcher IS triggered with **exactly the same code**.

[Codesandbox in Vue 2.6.11, watcher not triggering](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-snyder-57ics?file=/src/components/UselessRoute1.vue:734-796).

[Codesandbox in Vue 3.0, watcher IS triggered with exactly the same code](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-leftpad-98g2h?file=/src/App.vue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vue 2 there's reactivity issue when updating an item in an array or a nested field in an object, to solve this you've to use `this.$set()` method :

```
this.$set(this.data,newSectionId, {displayName: 'Custom'})
```

this issue is solved in Vue 3. and you could just do :

```
  const newSectionId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000); 
      this.data[newSectionId] = {
         displayName: 'Custom'
      }
```